# How to minimize additional code window in Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2013

Recently, due to changes in the hardware, I had to do full reinstall of my dev machine. After installing Visual Studio 2013 I noticed, that I no longer can minimize additional code windows residing on second display (the ones, which appear, when you "rip" a tab from the regular tab well). Also, these windows force stay on top of Visual Studio's main window.

How can I restore this behavior?

**Note**: You *can* RMB-click title of this window and choose "Minimize", but it minimizes in Windows 3.11-way - to small rectangle above the task bar. I want them to be regular additional windows visible on the taskbar as separate icons.

Answer (score 1):

Found out. Resharper is guilty in this case.

Ref: http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/28/resharper-71-early-access-is-open/#comment-69976